# Apache POI seeing columns in empty spreadsheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, libreoffice-calc

I have an empty spreadsheet, but when I'm accessing it with Apache POI (version 3.10), it says it has 1024 columns and 20 physical columns.
I really deleted all the cells, only some formatting remains, but no content.
And if I delete some columns with LibreOffice Calc (version 4.1.3.2), the number of columns only **increases**! What's going on?
Is there a reliable way to get the real number of columns (or cells in a row)?

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
        final URL url = new URL("http://aditsu.net/empty.xlsx");
        final Workbook w = WorkbookFactory.create(url.openStream());
        final Row r = w.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0);
        System.out.println(r.getLastCellNum());
        System.out.println(r.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you are not using the XSSF package? Try using that to read in xlsx.

Comment: As i know, cells with formatting is initialised, and same is the column with that style.

Comment: @anonymous WorkbookFactory is the preferred way to access spreadsheets. It uses XSSF or HSSF internally as needed.

Comment: Check after deleting the row...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh Then the row becomes null. But I may need to read a spreadsheet that has some data in it. The empty spreadsheet was an extreme example.

Comment: If a cell has formatting applied to it, then it isn't empty! That formatting information has to live somewhere, and that somewhere is as a blank cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more investigation, I think I figured out what's happening.

First, some terminology from POI: there are some cells that don't actually exist at all in the spreadsheet - those are called **missing**, or **undefined**/not defined. Then there are some cells that are defined, but have no value - those are called **blank** cells. Both types of cells appear empty in a spreadsheet program and can't be distinguished visually.

My spreadsheet has some blank cells that LibreOffice added at the end of the row (possibly a bug). When I delete columns, LibreOffice seems to shift the subsequent cells (including the blank ones) to the left, and adds more blank cells at the end (up to 1024).

And now the key part: neither `getLastCellNum()` nor `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` ignore blank cells. `getLastCellNum()` gives the last **defined** cell, and `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` gives the number of **defined** cells, both including blank cells. There doesn't seem to be any method available that skips blank cells. The javadoc for `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` is somewhat misleading - "if only columns 0,4,5 have values then there would be 3", but it's actually counting blank cells too, which don't really have values.

So the only solution I found is to loop through the cells and check if they are blank.

Side note: `getLastRowNum()` and `getFirstCellNum()` are 0-based but `getLastCellNum()` is 1-based, wtf?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some kind of formatting applied for you row. I have an empty xlsx file created with excel and method `getRow` produces null for empty rows.

Comment: You can check my file. Yes I may have some formatting, so what? There should still be a way to get the correct number of columns.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice its online

Comment: It seems that in your row 0 there are only few cells with some state, those are 1004-1023, don't know yet what is it.

Comment: Some LibreOffice weirdness maybe? Especially how the number of cells grows when I delete columns...

Comment: this might sound like a stupid question, but... how do you delete the column? do you mark cells and press delete or do you use action from context menu?

Comment: Select column(s), right-click, "Delete Selected Columns"

Comment: LibreOffice created or modified `xlsx` files seems to always have a ton of rows and columns that POI reads as not empty while they are. I've had Excel files with 5 rows come out with 65565(?) rows after editing with LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

@aditsu as per https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html, getLastCellNum() gets the index of the last cell contained in this row PLUS ONE.

+1 for libreOffice strugle! it's a bug, and in my opinion is very random. I'm getting null randomly, and often helps if I delete EMPTY rows (bellow) and EMPTY columns (on the right side).
...