# Apache POI (.xlsx) - null values - I want some to be ignored and other to use (to check if the required field is filled, for example)

Tags: java, excel, null, apache-poi, xlsx

I tried a lot of stuff but didn't come up with the good plan it seems.

My mini application fails sometimes with null error. Sometimes I think that I 'touched' some cell and sometimes I don't know why it happens. But when I delete empty rows and columns (near my filled rows) - all is good, no more null.

And I don't want a client to delete empty cells it's stupid.

And I also want to use some null values (if they are in my semi/filled row), so I can perform a check and see if required cell is filled.

But I don't want null values around my filled rows (right side and bellow).

Anyway, if someone understood above, here is the code as well:

```
    workbook.getSheetAt(11); 
    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row rows = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
            Cell cells = rows.getCell(c);
        if ((c == 0 && cells == null) || (c == 1 && cells == null)) {   

      //if required cells are not filled throw error or blabla

   }
 }
}
```

aand picture:

[null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjjgK.png)

Thank you!

Comment: When do you have your null pointer exception ? WHen you are making a `getCell()` ?

Comment: @Fizik26 Yes. I also tried with j < row.getLastCellNum() instead of number of columns I have.
Also, I'm using libreOffice insead of Excel, and I read this morning that it can be bug of the software: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070763/apache-poi-seeing-columns-in-empty-spreadsheet/58215306#58215306
I hope that's the case. Because it doesn't make sense